# Someone memorialized my Facebook profile but I'm still alive!

Tags: facebook, profile, facebook-abuse-reporting

Apparently, it’s pretty easy to memorialize someone's Facebook profile. I am greeted with the following message *after* entering my *valid* and *correct* username and password:

> Account Inaccessible This account is in a special memorial state. If you have any questions or concerns, please visit the Help Center for further information.

Help Center is useless as it only contains instructions on memorializing it. There are a number of blogs going back several years of persons who are victims of this particular kind of abuse. Apparently, you need my date of birth (which friends or friends with hacked accounts have access to) and a fake obituary (because no one at Facebook really reads them apparently).

The best part is that you can't actually contact them in any expedited way to protest. In fact, I sent an email to get a bunch of useless links that I'd already looked at.

Can anyone that has fallen into this entertaining conundrum offer some advice?

Comment: Are you sure you're still alive?

Comment: Typical for Facebook just to memorialize accounts without even thinking about verifying anything. A simple mail to you and a delay of let's say a week could have prevented lot's of cases where people got memorialized as a joke.

Comment: The link Erik posted is the correct form to get this fixed. Thanks for raising the issue - I've started a discussion for how we can make this experience better in the future for other people.

Comment: 'Two hunters are out in the woods when one of them collapses. He doesn't seem to be breathing and his eyes are glazed. The other guy whips out his phone and calls the emergency services. He gasps, "My friend is dead! What can I do?" The operator says "Calm down. I can help. First, let's make sure he's dead." There is a silence, then a gun shot is heard. Back on the phone, the guy says "OK, now what?"'

Comment: It’s perversely logical that you cannot contact them: as far as Facebook is concerned, you’re dead, remember?

Comment: After one dies, one's soul is transported to a different branch of the Facebook company for eternal exploitation.

Answer (score 54):

There is a special Facebook page for that: [My Personal Account is in a Special Memorialized State](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=292558237463098).

You can fill out a form, and it will be reviewed.

[image]

Comment: Though it is a right answer but it is not yet accepted by the user. I still doubt... "Is he alive?"

Comment: Haha, I'm ALIVE! I think I spatted out facebook hate about everywhere and forgot to come back here (I found the form later that day on my own.) Perhaps I'd found it quicker had I remembered to come back! Thanks! Hope I can still mark this as the answer after all this time.

Answer (score 18):

Well, whoever lied about you being dead did so under the penalty of perjury.

> IMPORTANT: Under penalty of perjury, this form is solely for the reporting of a deceased person to memorialize.

That said, the best course of action is probably to [Report a Violation of the Facebook Terms](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=274459462613911). You probably want to choose either, "Other abuse or harrassment," and fill out the detailed form that brings up.

[image]

Comment: First of all the fact that *they* say it is under penalty of perjury doesn't mean that it legally is. Second, according to the laws of which country? What if you are not in that country?