# A family member’s account

Tags: facebook

I have a question regarding my brother’s Facebook account. Someone reported him as deceased and this person was definitely not a family member. My sister and I are his only immediate family members. How can someone else do this?

Comment: To reverse this situation, there is some information here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28268/someone-memorialized-my-facebook-profile-but-im-still-alive

Answer (score 2):

> ### Report a Deceased Person's Profile
>
> **Relationship to the person**
>
> - Immediate family (spouse, parent, sibling, child)
> - Extended family (grandparent, aunt, uncle, cousin)
> - Non-family (friend, co-worker, classmate)
> - Other

[Source](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=305593649477238).